# Isn't "eventually" a word to describe the possibility?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm watching videos about a game, which one doesn't matter.

The commentator often says "and eventually win the game" but **everytime** he says this, he shows in fast-forward how the team really wins the game, so i asked myself, isnt "eventually" a word, that describes the possibility? So, "eventually win the game" should mean "there is the possibility, that this team wins the game, but also the possibility, they don't". Am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do [such and such] ... and you will eventually win the game.

*Eventually* means, literally, "in the event", where *event* has the sense "ultimate outcome, result".

In practice, *eventually* usually has the further sense of "after an indefinite time"; but it retains the sense of pointing to what happens in the end.

Consequently, *eventually* has the implication that the stated outcome is certain, not merely possible.

This is only an implication, however—the 'default' interpretation. You may 'cancel' this implication by saying so explictly, using terms which deny that the outcome is certain. For instance

> ... and you **may** eventually win the game.

Comment: Oh well, was confused because in German the word "eventuell" (which sounds similar) means maybe. Thanks.

Comment: @tkausl Yes; the Latin has evolved differently in English and German.

Comment: @tkausl Also don't confuse the adverb "eventually" with the noun "eventuality" (note the **i** at the end), which means "a possible outcome" or "a possibility". Unlike the adverb, that noun means that something *may* happen, not that it *must* happen.